# Same background color, different gradient width

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to get a background color on part of some `td`s, so that it looks similar to a progress bar background:
From left to somewhere in the middle, it's colored, and after that percentage, it's white.
And if it's 100%, of course, the whole `td` is colored.

The color, a `linear-gradient`, is the same on all `td`s, but the length will differ. I only have 3 lengths:

- 30%
- 70%
- 100%
- Also 0%, but it's just empty then, so this is out of the question

For this, I'm using a specific class for each variation, `.progress_**`.
Every class has two `linear-gradient`s on the `background` property.
This is my current working CSS:

```
.progress_30 {
    background:
        linear-gradient(to right,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 30%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 30%
        ),
        linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green)
    ;   
}
.progress_70 {
    background:
        linear-gradient(to right,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%
        ),
        linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green)
    ;   
}
.progress_100 {
    background:
        linear-gradient(to right,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
        ),
        linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green)
    ;   
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot that repeats.
I want at least to put the color in a separate `.progress` class, so it can be changed easily without altering the lengths, and so I can add or alter some lengths without touching the colors in the future.

So I tried this:

```
.progress {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
}
.progress_30 {
    background:
        linear-gradient(to right,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 30%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 30%
        )
    ;
}
.progress_70 {
    background:
        linear-gradient(to right,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%
        )
    ;
}
.progress_100 {
    background:
        linear-gradient(to right,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
        )
    ;
}
```

This doesn't fully work: the white part on the right is the correct length. But on the left, I don't see my `linear-gradient`, only the page's background color (which isn't white).

Is there a way I can get as few repetitions as possible in CSS, at least have the `linear-gradient`'s color set only once, or do I have to do it like in my first example?

Comment: you just have to repeat it - as you are stacking two gradient "images" they need to be in the same background declaration otherwise you are just overwriting one with the other.  The only thing you could do is add an extra element wrapper and put the shared style on that so it's extra html vs extra css, unless you use a pseudo element and position it absolutely at the back (but that seems like a dirty hack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on `background-size` and keep the gradient declaration within the same class:

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.progress {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) right no-repeat, 
   linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
}

.progress_30 {
  background-size: 70% 100%, auto;
}

.progress_70 {
  background-size: 30% 100%, auto;
}

.progress_100 {
  background-size: 0% 100%, auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress progress_30"></div>
<div class="progress progress_70"></div>
<div class="progress progress_100"></div>
```

You can simplify more using CSS variable in case you want to consider more percentage values:

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.progress {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) right/calc(100% - var(--p,50%)) 100% no-repeat, 
   linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="--p:30%"></div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:68%"></div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:80%"></div>

<div class="progress" ></div>
```

Comment: CSS variables are still a bit new to me, so I wouldn't have thought of using them that way, but I really like this approach, I'm going to use it. Thank you!